# Several module automatic to be launched at opening excel file but only one get launch (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros (refresh data, send to SQL) that I am expecting to launch at the openning of the excel file. 
However only one works at the opening. I need to launch manually the second module. Why? Thank you

Currently they are in different modules

```
Sub Auto_Open()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
------------
Private Sub SendtoSQL()

Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Dim ServerName As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim UserID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim NoOfFields As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim ColCounter As Integer

Set rs = New ADODB.recordset

ServerName = "xxx" ' Enter your server name here
DatabaseName = "xxx" ' Enter your  database name here
TableName = "xxx" ' Enter your Table name here
UserID = "xxx" ' Enter your user ID here
' (Leave ID and Password blank if using windows Authentification")
Password = "xxx" ' Enter your password here
NoOfFields = 43 ' Enter number of fields to update (eg. columns in your worksheet)
StartRow = 2 ' Enter row in sheet to start reading  records
EndRow = 37 ' Enter row of last record in sheet

 '  CHANGES
Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 '********

Set cn = New ADODB.connection

cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

cn.Execute "delete from " + TableName


rs.Open TableName, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

 'EndRow = shtSheetToWork.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For RowCounter = StartRow To EndRow
    rs.AddNew
    For ColCounter = 1 To NoOfFields
    'On Error Resume Next
        rs(ColCounter - 1) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, ColCounter)
    Next ColCounter
    Debug.Print RowCounter
Next RowCounter
rs.UpdateBatch

 ' Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `Auto_Open` is only refreshing all. How do you expect it to `SendToSql` if you don't tell it to?

Comment: How should I tell it to? Sorry i should have started with i dont have much vba knowledge. This query is the result of research on internet/ answers from forum

Comment: I don't see a reason for these to be in different modules. Move `SendToSQL` to the same module, and then add a new line in `Auto_Open`: `SendToSQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen said, simply add it to `Auto_Open` like this:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call SendToSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for `Call`. I didn't have that in my comment :)

Comment: @BigBen yea habit on my end sorry. People at my work like to see `call` as it shows another sub being, well, called. Can either keep or omit the word `call` both will work